# How do we rename Django PointField attribute names?

Tags: python, django

Currently when I set a PointField in my model, the JSON I receive is in this form:

```
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
                  121,
                   52,
                    0
               ]
```

Is there a way we can change `"type": "Point"` to `"type": "Vector"` and `"coordinates" : [...]` to `"xyz" : [...]`?

Would it be possible to achieve this renaming in our serializer?

Comment: Did you tried to override the `create()` method of `Serializer`?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge i took your advice and tried overriding create(self, validated_data) in my serializer, doing validated_data.pop(field name), then inserting a new customized field, but I don't think that is right implementation. May I get more assistance?

Comment: I don't think so. But, you could change `type` and `coordinates` to the required format in `form` also (I think it's possible and I'm not much familiar with `forms`)